# Symfony: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'doctrine_migration_versions' already exists

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine, migration, database-migration

I have a Postgres database which is separated in multiple schemas, every is used by a different symfony application and it has it's own migration versions table with a different name, when I try to run the migration command for the second time, a SQL error occurred:

> "onbaording.doctrine_migration_versions' already exists"

somehow this error occurs only in one of my applications.

I tried to precise the exact name of the migration table in my doctrine configuration in doctrine_migrations.yaml file:

```
doctrine_migrations:
    migrations_paths:
        # namespace is arbitrary but should be different from App\Migrations
        # as migrations classes should NOT be autoloaded
        'DoctrineMigrations': '%kernel.project_dir%/migrations'
    enable_profiler: '%kernel.debug%'
    connection: default
    storage:
        table_storage:
            table_name: 'onboarding.doctrine_migration_version'
```

I also tried to ads the name of the table in the schema filter in doctrine.yaml file:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        schema_filter: ~^(onboarding.doctrine_migration_version)$~
        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '13'
```

but nothing of this works.

PS: this error occurs only in the server and I couldn't reproduce it locally